# Import Multiple CSV Files Into Multiple New Tables In MySql

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have over a thousand CSV files from a DB2 database that I need to import into MySQL. Is there any way to automate the process of having a new table created by the name of the CSV file?

Example:

ACPINV.csv creates the tables ACPINV